# Customizing data annotation attributes for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to customize at runtime the attributes that MVC sees on a view model property. As far as I know, MVC relies internally on type descriptors to enumerate the attributes. Is there a way to hook a type descriptor somewhere to return a custom list of attributes for a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to hook a type descriptor somewhere to return a custom
>   list of attributes for a property?

It depends. If you want to override the Data Annotations used by the metadata provider then you could write your own custom [`ModelMetadataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and replace the default one ([`DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)). This allows you to have a custom metadata provider for a given type and return this information at runtime.

If on the other hand you are doing validation, then you are a bit out of luck. For more flexibility I would recommend you using [`FluentValidation.NET`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead of data annotations.